# Choosing an Option from a Browser Context Menu

Tags: c#, selenium, browser, selenium-webdriver

I'm attempting to write a method that will choose a specific option from the context menu of a browser. All of my research has led me to the solution of doing something like this:

```
var action = new Actions(driver);
action.ContextClick(element);
action.SendKeys(Keys.ArrowDown).SendKeys(Keys.ArrowDown);
action.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
action.Build().Perform();
```

However this does not seem to be working for me. Ideally I'd be able to choose which option to select based on the name or something similar, but the ability to just choose "option 2" or something like that would work as well.

Comment: Please show the HTML representation of the menu.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to fo it untill you will not perform complex ( or chained) actions (http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html) and will look like that:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(linkFilms).click(cssElement).perform();
```

The thing is you shoud not ending interacting with a page, otherwise menu focus will disappear.